# Do publishing and deployment mean the same?

Tags: deployment, packages

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio

> In Create a Hello World application with .NET Core in Visual Studio, you built a Hello World console application. In
>   Debug your Hello World application with Visual Studio, you tested it using the Visual Studio debugger. Now that
>   you're sure that it works as expected, you can **publish** it so that other users can run it. **Publishing** creates the set of
>   files that are needed to run your application. To **deploy** the files, copy them to the target machine.

What do publishing and deployment mean?

- Is it correct that deployment means that after building/compiling programs in development machines, and packaging, copy the package to the production machine?
- Is it correct that deployment does not include building and packaging?
- Does publishing mean building/compiling programs and packaging on development machines? (I was once asked to "publish" (or "deploy", I forget which word) created by others. It was
  actually to click a few buttons  (I forgot which) in Visual Studio IDE, maybe related
  to the web server, but all this was done on a development machine. It seemed to me to build and package the program.)
- Does publishing not include deployment?
- Do publishing and deployment mean the same?

  The above quote seems to say no.

  But  [Publish .NET Core apps with the CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) being a subsection of [.NET Core application deployment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) seems to say yes.

  Literally doesn't publishing mean move something to a publicly accessible place? Isn't that the same as deployment?

Are the two words standard (or generally used) in software engineering, including outside dotnet e.g. Java, C++, Python, ...? What other standard or popular words that are used instead, if any?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is unclear from their description _"**Publishing** _**creates the set of files**_ that are needed to run your application. To **deploy** the files, _**copy them to the target machine**_."_ (emphasis mine)? These terms are widely used. Think about stuff published via GitHub, where a wide varitey of programming languages and software ecosystems are used.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Maybe clear to you. But please read my post. I have changed it.

Comment: Literally doesn't publishing mean move something to a publicly accessible place? Isn't that the same as deployment?

Comment: No, delpoyment is literally to _"copy them to the target machine"_, where _target machine_ is the machine where the application is meant to run at. No matter if this is a web server, a desktop computer or a mobile phone.

Comment: What about "publishing"? Literally doesn't publishing mean move something to a publicly accessible place? Doesn't publishing literally not include creating the things to be made publicly accessible?  Isn't that the same as deployment?

Comment: Though the machine (server) serving to copy those sets of files from isn't meant to run the application. Deployment means to copy the files to a target machine which is meant to run the application (as mentioned).

Comment: What about "publishing"?  You seem to avoid it, and probably haven't seen it. If you have confusions or   uncertainty, then so do I.

Comment: I don't have any uncertainy. _Publishing_ just means to copy those sets of files to a place where they can be publicly accessed from.

Comment: Or do you? You basically copy "Publishing just means to copy those sets of files to a place where they can be publicly accessed from"  from my second comment, which exactly makes me think that publishing and deployment are the same. Your was "Publishing _creates the set of files that are needed to run your application" in your first comment. Do you realize the unnecessary adversary that your  first comment has put on my post, though I understand and appreciate you are trying to help. I have been suffering worse attacks these days, because of discrimination on my posts and account.

Comment: Are you actually confused what the term _target machine_ exactly makes as a difference within the context of _publishing_ and _deployment_? In the 1st case the _target machine_ plays the role to make those files accessible, whereas in the 2nd case the _target machine_ should finally run the application.

Comment: Publishing a book: I put it on a shelf in the bookstore. Deploying the book: You buy the book from the bookstore and start reading.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ could you please post a reply that summarize and clarify what you wrote? I always upvote replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Do publishing and deployment mean the same?

No, these terms definitely don't mean the same.

Copying files to a *target machine* appears in different context and purpose:

> > **Publishing** creates the set of files that are needed to run your application

you copy these to a machine where they can be publicly accessed from

vs.

> > To **deploy** the files, copy them to the target machine.

you copy these to a machine where you intend to run the application.